# A script copied through the dockerfile cannot be found after I run docker with -w

Tags: docker

I have the following Dockerfile

```
FROM ros:kinetic
COPY . ~/sourceshell.sh
RUN["/bin/bash","-c","source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash"]
```

when I did this (after building it with `docker build -t test`

```
docker run --rm -it test /bin/bash
```

I had a bash terminal and I could clearly see there was a `sourceshell.sh` file that I could even execute from the Host

However I modified the docker run like this

```
docker run --rm -it -w "/root/afolder/" test /bin/bash
```

and now the file `sourceshell.sh` is nowhere to be seen.

Where do the files copied in the dockerfile go when the working directory is reasigned with docker run?

Answer (score 0):

Option "-w" is telling your container execute commands and access on/to  "/root/afolder" while your are COPYing "sourceshell.sh" to the context of the build, Im not sure, you can check into [documentation](http://FROM%20ros:kinetic%20COPY%20.%20%7E/sourceshell.sh%20RUN%5B%22/bin/bash%22,%22-c%22,%22source%20/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash%22%5Dhttps://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) but i think also "~" is not valid either. In order to see your file exactly where you access you should use your dockerfile like this bellow otherwise you would have to navigate to your file with "cd":

```
FROM ros:kinetic
WORKDIR /root/afolder
COPY . ./sourceshell.sh
RUN["/bin/bash","-c","source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash"]
```

Just in case you don't understand the diff of the build and run process:
the code above belongs to the the build context, meaning, first build and image (the one you called it "test"). then the command:

```
 docker run --rm -it -w "/root/afolder/" test /bin/bash
```

runs a container using "test" image and use WORKDIR "/root/afolder"